# refreshing a view after a POST/PUT/DELETE operation

Tags: angularjs

I am doing a relatively simple CRUD application where I list, in my case, contracts with some key information, and basically can update/add/delete contracts to that list. The database is on my MySQL server.
Hence I am using here some php files to translate information from AngularJS to the database

For the list of contracts I use a GET method on $http like so

```
$scope.fetch = function(){

    $scope.method = 'GET';
    $scope.url = 'dataFetch.php';
    $scope.code = null;
    $scope.response = null;

    $http({method: $scope.method, url: $scope.url, cache: $templateCache}).
        success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.status = status;
            $scope.data = data;
        }).
        error(function(data, status) {
            alert('failed');
        }); 
}
```

the dataFetch php file is making a connection to the database and queries all entries. Then this data is back in the success method where I grab it into the $scope and display it for the user. Kind of basic.

Now similarly, I do the POST, DELETE and PUT methods, all working nicely.

After I do the above (POST, DELETE and PUT) and change my view back from the details view to the contract list view and would expect that all changes are updated.
To do this, I launch the above dataFetch() function before going to the view by the $location service.

Now, my problem is that my contracts listing does not show the updated list despite it has run the dataFetch()

Any clue why this happens and what could be the solution

Many thanks
Peter

Comment: Are you caching requests on your server?

Comment: Not sure as I am not an expert. I inject $templateCache in the controller where I am defining the fetch function. In the controller where I add a new contract, I don't use this injector.

Comment: Try removing the `cache` option from your $http call